# Remote Desktop Access from Mac to Linux Redhat

Tags: linux, macos, vnc, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am new to linux, so please bear with me!

Assume:

1) I do not have physical access to my Linux (Redhat 6) machine and no VNC (or other remote desktop server) is set up on the Linux machine.
2) I am connected to Linux from Mac via VPN client

From the very first steps and from the command line of my mac (ssh access to both username of interest and root), what is the best way to start remote desktop access from mac to linux?

According to http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN283098/EN I must set up a VNC server (i.e. install TigerVNC). However because I do not have "connectivity to RHN or a Satellite Server", I must create a local 'yum' repository in accordance with http://www.dell.com/support/article/SLN266089/en. This page in turn requires firs to "Download RHEL media ISO to server and notate path", and I do not know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

If the redhat 6 machine is properly registered, you should be able to run 'yum install tigervnc' 
if that doesn't work, then your redhat 6 machine is not properly registered, and you will need to address that first.